# Is there a way to trigger a Rxjs timer on demand in addition to the preset n milliseconds?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created an app that, among other things, shows scores of a certain product. I want to update those scores every 5 seconds, but only when the page is shown. If the user is on another page, the updating should stop.

I created a polling function using the timer from rxjs in my ScoresService. When the `ScoresComponent` (that shows the scores) is loaded (ngOnInit), it subscribes to `scores$`. When `ScoreComponent` is destroyed (ngOnDestroy) it unsubscribes from `scores$`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScoresService {

  product: Product;
  scores$: Observable<Score[]>

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private mainService: MainService
  ) {
    // set a timer for every 5 seconds, starting now, to get scores
    this.scores$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.getScores())
    );


    // when the product is set or changed, update this.product
    this.mainService.product$.subscribe((product) => {
       this.product = product;
       // fire the timer again?
    }
  }

  getScores(): Observable<Score[]> {
    const params = {
      order: 'best',
      from: moment().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      till: moment().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      limit: '100',
      product: this.product.id
    };

    return this.http.get<Score[]>(`${api_url}`', { params });
  }

}
```

So the timer works, when the product is set of course. It only fetches new scores when `ScoreComponent` subscribes to `scores$`. But the problem occurs when the product is changed, because it takes between 0 and 5 seconds to get the new scores. Is there a way to fire the timer on demand, for instance when the product is changed. If there are other ways to achieve this, I would hear about it. The only thing that should be noted is that only when someone is subscribed to `scores$` the polling should occur. I don't want endless polling of the endpoint if no one needs the new scores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the observables from product and the timer. This will fire the getScores everytime there is a new product, and start a new timer for every 5 seconds to get the scores.

```
export class ScoresService {
  product: Product;
  scores$: Observable<Score[]>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private mainService: MainService
  ) {
    // set a timer for every 5 seconds, starting now, to get scores
    this.scores$ = this.mainService.product$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000)),
      switchMap(() => this.getScores())
    );

    this.mainService.product$.subscribe((product) => {
       this.product = product;
    }
  }

  getScores(): Observable<Score[]> {
   // ...
  }
}
```

It feels like you should not use a product property in this service though, and let it all be streams. This will prevent unnecessary subscriptions. You can also add a `shareReplay` to have any subsequent subscriptions receive the latest emitted value from the http call:

```
export class ScoresService {
  readonly product$: Observable<Product> = this.mainService.product$;

  readonly scores$: Observable<Score[]> = this.product$.pipe(
    switchMap((product) => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.getScores(product.id))
    )),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  ); 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private mainService: MainService) {}

  getScores(id: number): Observable<Score[]> {
   // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, this almost works. When i unsubscribe from `scores$` the scores are still fetched every 5 seconds. (I tried your 2nd suggestion)

Comment: @fieldhof that's my bad, the downside of using `shareReplay(1)`. To prevent this, you have to use the options object and set refCount to true. I'll update my answer

Comment: this seems to work. Any downside using `refCount: true`?

Comment: @fieldhof if you unsubscribe and immediately resubscribe a http request is fired again, so the last value is not cached. But in this case that's not really an issue. I tend to always use the refCount: true option, to prevent ongoing observables

Comment: That's not an issue at all. Thanks for the answer and the explanation. You sir, made my day : )